# How to transfer orders and customer data from magento 2.3.0 to 2.3.2?

Tags: php, database-migration, magento-2.3

I have live ecommerce site running on magento 2.3.0. Now am building a modified version using magento 2.3.2 in localhost. So i want to transfer all customers, orders, invoices and products data to my new database. How can i do that?

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Remember that you will get more and better answers if you include in your question what you have done so far and what is the exact problem that prevents you from achieving the desired goal

Comment: @Nicolás Carrasco   I made a fresh installation of magento 2.3.2 in dev server. and i have old magento 2.3.0 db backup. I need to transfer all orders, customers, products, categories etc to my newly installed magento.. I dont know how to transfer only these datas to new magento. which ever tables i need to import ?

Comment: there are many plugins which do this for you and i think magento already have import export are where you can export/import products, orders, customers etc. If not then you can use firebear import/export extension which support almost any type of data.

Answer (score 0):

You could just go into your DB and export the whole thing however theres probably a few MB of data.

I am not affiliated with this product however it been around for years and I personally use it - [Navicat](https://www.navicat.com/en/) as I can just sync my database on demand or at timed intervals.